# Need advice modelling a large application with EXTJS 4.2

Tags: extjs4.2

I am currently working with a Banking firm, we have a requirement to develop a fairly complex but Rich UI application. We are using EXTJS 4.2 and Spring MVC.

The first release of the app went into Production about a month back. 
Now while modelling the new phase, we have come across a major hurdle. The application load up time is fairly high at this point of time. This is happening because the application has followed a single Page web 2.0 model and multiple JS files which when minified -> all-classes.js is 3 MB.

Now there is a lot of work to be done going ahead in order to build additional functionality.
Since all code is getting loaded at once during startup it would take a lot of time for this.

I figured out a design but I am not sure if that would help.. If we divide our application into multiple pages each have a different --> all-classes.js , will it help improve the performance ?

I need some advice on this.
You can refer to this links which I found :
 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/command_app_multi
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130449-Large-Single-Page-Architecture-in-ExtJS-4.0/page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are a number of answers to this, the best of which is "it depends".

Splitting into multiple pages is obviously going to produce some performance improvements. After all, you'll (presumably) have smaller files to initially load, fewer controllers to instantiate, etc.

The question is how much? I'm not sure I can answer that very well, without knowing more about the app and how it's structured.

I do know this, however. I have an app whose all-classes.js is around 2 MB. While there is obviously the initial hit loading it, subsequent visits use a cached version of it. And even the initial load of the 2MB file is pretty fast on most decent connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will briefly elaborate about the app. The application will be used to store account related information and also relationship, The UI will become complex down the line. Now the problem as I said, we already have followed single page model and it solves our purpose for now, the issue that we might come across is that what will happen when the **all-classes.js** file grows big.

Comment: We have cached the JS files, but initial loading takes long time. Can you suggest any examples of the same of how to implement across multiple pages. Details of which I could not find much.

Comment: **all-classes.js** itself takes **36.62s** to load, in total application take s more than a minute in Dev env. We have load balanced Prod env, which will improve the performance for sure, but still on a single server it's slow.

Comment: If your caching headers are sent correctly from the http server, the load time should be virtually zero, except for the first load. Also, 3M taking 37s is just too much - it would be 81kB/s if we only count the network speed. See if it is the real network download time or the server processing time.

Comment: Yes, Initial load time is what I am talking about, later the application is working smoothly, this time again I checked the time it took **21s**.  Generating the DOM of the entire application leads to taking so long. If we load only the landing page related DOM the load time is improved but later when migrating to other screens DOM related to other screens are loaded. But the issue here the old DOM which is not active is still present in the viewport.

Comment: I think not loading the other DOM's at initial load is the approach I will follow, coz it is less complex and improves the performance.  Thanks you all for the help